Identification of a good BDW93C Darlington transistor
I have two different 'BDW93C' from two different suppliers. They show two different readings,
I want to know whether they are good or counterfeit, here are the readings.

I believe the original parts have two base-emitter resistors in addition to a collector-emitter diode.
Thank you

(Base resistor & "anti-parallel diode" is what the datasheet says.)

The one you labeled counterfeit looks like what you would expect from a single NPN.
You might try hooking it up on a breadboard and measuring the DC current gain at an Ic that won’t need a heatsink for a quick test.
You should be able to measure  relatively low resistance (10k or less) with your probes connected  reverse bias across the BE, and read the anti-parallel diode voltage drop, that you can’t points to it being a fake, probably a cheap NPN re-marked.
The ‘original’ looks more reasonable, you might expect Vbe to be a bit higher for a Darlington but the second transistor’s base emitter is going to make it read lower and the current you meter measures it at and temperature will affect it as well, you can see a pretty wide range of readings on a transistor or diode just by holding it in your fingers. Vbe can get up to around 5 V at higher currents, check the datasheet.
Also, looking at the package type compared to the manufacturer’s datasheet can sometimes suss out a fake.

(Sadly, Uni-Trend does not state diode test current in the specifications. Assuming 1 mA, I'm looking at one $V_F$ + 150 mV - with 10 mA, it's likely $2 V_F$.)
